# Function that takes the input from a question, and uses that input in the main function

Tags: c++, string, function

I am currently writing a program to do a simulation of chutes and ladders. For the user, the first thing to show up in the console box would be asking for the player 1's name, and player 2's name. Obviously, I could just do cout << "name 1?" and cin as a variable. However, in this assignment, we would get extra credit if we make a function that takes this input to use it in the main function. In other words, how should I write a function so that when called, it brings the input that we returned? I have tried for a while, and still can't figure it out. Here is a psuedocode of what I am trying

```
string GetPlayerNames(string player1Name, string player2Name);

int main ()
{
string GetPlayerNames(player1Name, player2Name); // Calling the function
// rest of code for the game
}

string GetPlayerNames(string player1Name, string player2Name)
{
cout << "What is the name of player 1? ";
cin >> player1Name;
return player1Name;
cout << "What is the name of player 2? ";
cin >> player2Name;
return player2Name;
}
```

Optimally, this is what the output should look like when running the program.

> What is the name of player 1? *enter the name*
>
> What is the name of player 2? *enter the name*
>
> runs the game using the two player names

Sorry for the noob question, I am a very new programmer! Appreciate any help I can get here.

Comment: A function can only return one value. You could return a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can only return one value. You could return a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::pair;
using std::string;

pair<string, string> GetPlayerNames();

int main ()
{
    auto [player1Name, player2Name] = GetPlayerNames(); // Calling the function
// rest of code for the game
}

pair<string, string> GetPlayerNames()
{
    string player1Name, player2Name;
    cout << "What is the name of player 1? ";
    cin >> player1Name;
    cout << "What is the name of player 2? ";
    cin >> player2Name;
    return std::make_pair(player1Name, player2Name);
}
```

Instead of returning the names you could use references

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::pair;
using std::string;

void GetPlayerNames(string &player1Name, string &player2Name);

int main ()
{
    string player1Name, player2Name;
    GetPlayerNames(player1Name, player2Name); // Calling the function
// rest of code for the game
}

void GetPlayerNames(string &player1Name, string &player2Name)
{
    cout << "What is the name of player 1? ";
    cin >> player1Name;
    cout << "What is the name of player 2? ";
    cin >> player2Name;
}
```

Comment: This looks great, will use in the future. Thank you! Have not seen it before. However, this teacher will just give us a 0 on the assignment if we use something we have not learned about in her notes. Will also report us to the college for cheating. Which is ironic because over half of her class is failing, it is an online class and her notes are terrible. Oh well. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @AdamKeller You should probably mention this in your question and list all allowed C++ tools. We can't know your notes.

Comment: @AdamKeller I added another function to my question.

Comment: I see. Using your code, I now get the three following errors:

E0308: more than one instance of overloaded function "GetPlayerNames" matches the argument list

C0282: redefinition of formal parameter 'player1Name'
C0282: redefinition of formal parameter 'player1Name'

Comment: @AdamKeller I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Pass them by reference. Boom you don't need to return anything.

```
void get_name(string & , string &);
int main()
{
    string player1 , player2;
    cout<<player1<<player2<<endl;
    get_name(player1, player2);
    cout<<player1<<player2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
void get_name(string &player1, string & player2)
{
    cout<<"Enter names\n";
    cin>>player1>>player2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can create a function that will read a string for you, you need to provide a way to indicate whether the function *succeeded* or *failed* in actually reading and storing the string. Otherwise on any stream error, or if the user generates a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows), if you fail to catch it, bad things will happen.

This isn't specific to this read string function, it is true with every function that completes some task that the remaining code depends on. *"Validate, validate, validate"* is the rule. A simple integer returning `1` on success or `0` on failure is fine (or vice-versa, your choice). `bool` is also a simple type for indicating success/failure.

In your case, you care about whether the read succeeded (which depends on `std::ios_base::iostate` after the read). The beauty is you don't need to check the minutia of `.eof(), .fail()`, or `.bad()` (though you are free to), you simply check the return of your input function (using `getline` may be preferable to `>>` for handling whitespace, as well as any extraneous characters). Here you could simply do something like:

```
#include <iostream>

bool getstring (std::string& str, const std::string prompt)
{
    std::cout << prompt;    /* output prompt */

    /* fill str, return true/false for success/failure */
    return getline (std::cin, str) ? true : false;
}
```

Which allows you to pass the prompt to display to the user, and then returns `true/false` based on whether the call to `getline` succeeds.

In `main()` you can simply check whether your `getstring` function succeeded or failed before relying on the information in your string `s`, e.g.

```
int main (void) {

    std::string s,
                prompt {"enter "};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (getstring(s, prompt + "player " + (char)('1' + i) + ": "))
            std::cout << s << "\n\n";
        else {
            std::cout << "(stream error or user canceled input)\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

(which also lets you use the default ability to concatenate `std::string` in forming the prompt -- so long as you have no more than nine players using the method above)

This will handle your player input, including whitespace in the name, and while handling a manually generated `EOF` at any of the inputs. A short example with two players would be:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/chutes
enter player 1: Mickey Mouse
Mickey Mouse

enter player 2: Goofy Dog
Goofy Dog
```

Or if the user generates a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows):

```
$ ./bin/chutes
enter player 1: (stream error or user canceled input)
```

There are many ways you can put the pieces together, but always remember to *validate, validate, validate* every user input. Let me know if you have further questions.